# Using "return" for data types and declaring IBOutlets and IBActions in custom classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to the site, first time poster so I hope I do this right. I'm doing some tutorials and I have a couple of questions that I can't get answers to even though I see some other questions on here that are similar but have answers that don't seem to relate to my issue. I'm also using Xcode 5.

Fist question, when are you required to use return "data type" in methods? I know you use it when dealing with int. For example:

```
-(int)methodName{

    _count++
    return _count;
}
```

Are integers the only time I need to worry about that? Obviously I don't need it for -(void) methods.

Second question. I have a button and label in my story board (interface builder). When I click the label or button in the storyboard and drag over to my custom class .h it just ignores it. I tried writing out my label and button by hand and then drag from the little circle to the button and label but same thing. Is this because I'm trying to do it in a custom class and not the main ViewController? Is that a no, no? Thanks for any help with my questions, much appreciated.

Comment: Your questions, answers are toooo broad.

Comment: You have to have a return statement for any method that has a return type other than void (or IBAction which is actually typed to void).

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that guys. Thanks for the answer on using the return type. Much appreciated. I'll rewrite my other question and do a new post.